# How do I handle cases where using a fractional exponent gives me NaN?

Tags: javascript

My Javascript code is trying to multiple three decimal or integer numbers and raise them to the exponent 0.16 but the exponentiation results in NaN. In the specific case I am testing, the three decimal numbers I'm multiplying are the constant 0.3965, and the variables -40 and 40 which yields a product of -634.4 (to one decimal place). The formula in question is the first one shown (the one used by Environment Canada) in this subsection of the Wikipedia article on [Wind Chill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chill#North_American_and_United_Kingdom_wind_chill_index) and I'm getting the NaN on the fourth term of the equation.

After some googling, I've learned that when an exponent is fractional, the result is sometimes a real number and sometimes an imaginary number. Am I right in assuming that I'm getting NaN when the result is an imaginary number?

Regardless of why I'm getting NaN, how do I change my code so that I get a meaningful result that **is** a number, at least for reasonable values of the variables like I am using? I have no prior experience with exponentiation of a fractional number in Javascript (or any other programming language for that matter).

Here's the essence of my code:

```js
var TempC = -40; //Temperature in Celsius
var WindKph = 40; //Wind speed in kph
var TempWindChill; //Temperature in Celsius with wind chill applied
TempWindChill = 13.12 + (0.6215 * TempC) - ((11.37 * WindKph) ** 0.16) + ((0.3965 * TempC * WindKph) ** 0.16);
console.log("TempWindChill = " + TempWindChill);
```

If you'd like to play with the code a bit, you can clone it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-morning-32zf6?file=/index.html).

Also, I'm puzzled by a related matter. When I look at the arithmetic operators in Javascript (at W3Schools), there is no exponentiation operator! I can successfully exponentiate in Javascript using the `**` operator yet that operator isn't listed in the documentation. Here's a link to the  [W3Schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp). Is their documentation just faulty or is exponentiation a feature that is not officially present in the language?

Comment: W3Schools is generally outdated and just kinda bad. MDN is more up to date. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation

Comment: *"If you'd like to play with the code a bit, you can clone it here."* Please use Stack Snippets for runnable examples (the `<>` button, [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)), not off-site resources. Four reasons: It's really easy to leave something crucial out of the question and only include it in the off-site code; people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: Negative bases with fractional exponents return `NaN`

Comment: Picking up on @Pointy's point, maybe you could work in Kelvin and then convert the result to C? (I have no idea about wind chill calculations, it just would just let you use 233.15 instead of -40 for for the temperature of -40C.

Comment: @Pointy - I can't believe you are correct. Environment Canada apparently uses this formula and the only quantity in the fourth term of the equation that could conceivably be negative is the ambient temperature, which I call TempC in my code. Temperatures that are below zero Celsius are not remotely exceptional in Canada.

Comment: @AKX - Thanks for clearing that up. I was quite surprised that an operation as fundamental as exponentiation was (apparently) missing from the language.

Comment: @Henry https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow#using_math.pow

Comment: @Pointy - The only way I can reconcile the reality of Javascript and the (assumed) accuracy of the Wind Chill formula in Wikipedia is that Environment Canada is NOT using Javascript for the calculation. That's fine: now I have to find a more appropriate language. Thanks for helping me figure that out!

Comment: @Henry - No, no, no.  You implemented the formula for WindChill incorrectly.  See my answer below before you go off the deep end.

Comment: @Henry - I'm literally screaming into my monitor over this issue trying to convince you. :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thanks for explaining the preferred way of dealing with code snippets. It turns out that I won't need to figure out how to change that calculation so that it works for Kelvin: I wrote the formula incorrectly. Luckily, selbie caught my mistake and now all is well :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula for Windchill is incorrect, hence the complex number issue that Jiří Cihelka cites in their answer.

```
TempWindChill = 13.12 + (0.6215 * TempC) - ((11.37 * WindKph) ** 0.16) + ((0.3965 * TempC * WindKph) ** 0.16);
```

Referencing [this site](https://sciencing.com/calculate-wind-chill-factor-5981683.html):
Should be:

```
Wind chill = 13.12 + 0.6215T – 11.37 (V^0.16) + 0.3965T (V^0.16)
```

Let's fix your code:

```js
var TempC = -40; //Temperature in Celsius
var WindKph = 40; //Wind speed in kph
var v = WindKph ** .16;
var TempWindChill = 13.12 + .6215*TempC - 11.37*v + .3965*TempC*v;
console.log("TempWindChill = " + TempWindChill);
```

result:

`TempWindChill = -60.873447728482546`

Comment: Thank you VERY much for seeing my error! I've had almost nothing to do with math in many years now and I mistakenly thought that a*b*(c**d) was the same as (a*b*c)**d. For what it's worth, if I remove ALL of the parentheses from the original TempWindChill formula I posted, I get exactly the right answer without needing v at all. You've saved me considerable time by pointing out my error and I appreciate that!

Comment: The `v` variable is so your code doesn't do a redundant and expensive calculation twice.  Runtime might optimize that out.  In any case, I'm glad you got steered to the root cause of your bug.

Comment: I figured that the v variable was an optimization. I'm just not worried about it because this is only proof-of-concept code at best at this stage so I'm not worried about performance yet. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot raise a negative number to a fractional exponent and remain in real numbers. The result would be a [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). JavaScript does not support complex numbers by default.

Comment: Cihelka - Clearly, I need to use a language that is better than Javascript to make this calculation! Thanks for helping me understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Henry - no Javascript is a perfectly fine language. It's just that you are using the wrong formula for WindChill. See my answer below on how to fix your code.